# Removing cell from UITableView and correspondent file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a table view with many cells. If I swipe on any of them, a delete button appears, and if I press it the cell disappears, but when I reload the table, it reappears. the file which is loading from is a txt file of this kind:

```
row1, row2, row3, row4, row5...
```

How can I remove one of the row from the file, so remove for example row3...

...and have...

```
row1, row2, row4, row5...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Example file contents
NSString *fileContents = @"row1, row2, row3, row4, row5";

// Separate the titles into an array
NSMutableArray *titles = [[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] mutableCopy];

// Remove row3 (at index 2 because indexes start from 0
[titles removeObjectAtIndex:2];

// Combine the array back into a string
NSString *result = [titles componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

// Log the result for debugging
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Prints: `row1, row2, row4, row5`

This example code creates a string that looks like your text file, splits it into an array, removes one index, then combines the modified array back into a string.

Hopefully you will find some of this code useful (I gather you would already have some of it or something similar in use).

Comment: but since I don't know the index of the object, it has to be the same as the row number

Comment: If you use the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, just use `indexPath.row` to get the index of the row that was selected.